# transforming exchange rate and inflation rate

Tags: r, data-transformation, logarithm, percentage

I am testing some variables in percentage (exchange rate, inflation, and GDP growth rate), and I am a bit hesitate whether it is better leave them as percentage or transform them into log values.
thanks

Comment: That is an important question, but it is really more of a substantive / theoretical question than a statistical / methodological question.

Comment: @gung is right, but more can be said. As inflation and GDP growth can be zero or negative, then in principle taking the logarithm makes little sense, regardless of whether negative or zero values occur in your data. Another way to see that logarithms are dubious is to realise that logarithmic scale means that the difference between 0.001 and 0.01% growth is equivalent to that 1% and 10%: does that make economic sense to you? Exchange rates can be viewed reciprocally, so it is a matter of convenience which way you represent them, and logarithms _could_ make sense too, so far as I can see.

Comment: @Nick Perhaps what the OP had in mind is the distinction between using $ r/100$ and $\log(1 + r/100)$ when $r$ is the percentage growth rate. Then negative values of $r$ cause no problems (unless someone is foolish enough to quote growth rates of less than -100%!).

Comment: @whuber Indeed, I can't rule that out, but I would have hoped that to be explicit.

Comment: whuber wrote "unless someone is foolish enough to quote growth rates of less than -100%".  I saw that happen a few weeks ago. The editor of a fairly large technology investment oriented blog employing several writers and editors claimed a price decrease of 158%. She would not acknowledge her error even after I pointed out the flaw in her calculation. On a similar note, I saw a PH.D. physicist who spent 2 years full time on a model break the unity barrier in probability based on using a 2 term Taylor series approximation - he didn't realize it until I pointed it out. 120% chance of success.

Answer (score 1):

It's more or less the same thing, other than whether the rates are expressed on a simple compounding basis, in which case perhaps use percentage vs. on a continuous compounding basis (think exp), in which case perhaps use log. If there's no compounding going on, it really shouldn't matter at all.

Edit: I was sloppy because I was rushing out the door.  I had in mind what whuber wrote in his comment directly under the question, but did not state that.

Comment: In light of the comment by @Nick Cox pointing out that logarithms of negative numbers will make no sense, could you be specific about what two things you claim are the same?